# How to scale kafka and zookeeper with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm all new to kafka and zookeeper. I'm trying to run 3 zookeeper nodes and 3 kafka brokers with docker-compose's --scale functionality. But somehow zookeeper instances won't sync (I guess) and brokers will end up in different clusters. Sometimes 2-1, sometimes 1-1-1. Either way they will not be aware of each other because when I try to create a topic with 3 partitions and 3 replications it will give me an error saying the number of available brokers are less than the replication factor. This is not the case when I don't scale zookeeper but only kafka with `docker-compose up --scale kafka=3`. Then I can see with `kafka-cluster.sh` that all of the brokers are in the same cluster.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
    
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
```

At the end of the day what I'm trying to achive is run 3 zookeepers, 3 brokers, and one nifi instance to publish and consume messages with from kafka. I know having 3 instances of kafka and zookeeper on the same machine doesn't make sense, but I'm trying to understand how this all works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use the scale CLI because all brokers will end up with with same `broker.id` value, and conflict with each other in Zookeeper.

You'll need to define three separate brokers (you don't need 1 Zookeeper per broker) in the YAML

e.g.

- https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-single-kafka-multiple.yml
- https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose/blob/master/zk-multiple-kafka-multiple.yml

Or instead use something like Minikube with the Strimzi Kafka operator that can appropriately define container replicas. There's also probably a Nifi Helm Chart or Operator that exists.

Comment: Once I've defined zookeeper nodes explicitly and passed in ZOO_SERVERS as env variables to zookeeper nodes I could scale kafka just fine. Zookeeper cluster handled id assignments. Each broker had a unique id, connected to the same cluster.

Comment: Do the clients work? What about `advertised.listeners`?

Comment: Clients work fine. I'm not exactly sure whether it was because zookeepers needed different ID's or they needed to know all the zoo.servers. I set advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 and zookeeper.connect=<all zoo_servers>. That way I can scale kafkas and use their automatically configured host names in docker compose's internal network when connecting via Nifi.

Comment: One potential issue is if the broker restarts for any reason, I don't think it'll persist the same ID.